# WPF application won't execute when i add simple event

Tags: wpf, events

I have a window, in which i have many controls,  UserControls or controls derived from other controls (and grids and frames).

It works fine if i DON'T add any event to ANY of the controls i have in my window (in XAML). I have many other events that don't cause this, but if i add a new event. It will crash.

Example:

This is the control i would like to add my event to:

```
<con:MyControl Content="Hello" Grid.Column="3" Width="90"/>
```

So, i change it into:

```
<con:MyControl Content="Hello" Grid.Column="3" Width="90" Click="Hello_Click"/>
```

The application compiles...

But then, this happens:

```
'Set connectionId threw an exception.' Line number '53' and line position '22'.
```

InnerException:

```
{"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Button' to type 'MyNamespace.MyClass.MyControl'."}
```

If i now remove

```
Click="Hello_Click"
```

It works perfectly fine!

Comment: Does MyControl properly derive from System.Windows.Controls.Button?

Comment: Look in the stack trace to see who's doing the invalid cast. Chances are there's some other logic hooked up that you're not thinking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Anurag. If you have a button elsewhere on your client that is hosting MyControl you may be able to attach the button event to your control by changing Click="Hello_Click" to Button.Click="Hello_Click". But you would need to have a button further down the logical hierachy so its event could bubble up to your control. The error suggests that MyControl does not subclass Button.

Comment: The XAML for the control is here: http://pastebin.com/m35792d4b

The C# is here: http://pastebin.com/m3ecfa90c